# How to stay within vector range?

Tags: c++, vector

I am currently having some problems with staying within a range in a vector.

In the following code I was trying to check if a number which is being checked is smaller or equal to number after it

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>

bool fun(std::vector<int> v)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    {
        if(v.at(i) <= v.at(i+1))
        {
            // code
        }
    }
    return true;
}

int main()
{    
    std::vector<int> v { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 };

    try
    {
        std::cout << fun(v);
    }
    catch(std::out_of_range range_problem)
    {
        std::cout << "EXCEPTION: " << range_problem.what();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Due to `at()` , function is throwing an exception, so the code above outputs this:

`EXCEPTION: vector::_M_range_check`

I thought about adding `if(i+1 == v.size() - 1) break;` in the for loop, but that means that I wouldn't be able to compare last two elements in that vector.

Can anyone recommend a solution to this problem?

Thanks

Comment: How about changing the condition of `for` loop to `i < v.size() - 1;` ?

Comment: Thanks there is no alternative solution? In case I wanted to save some of those checked values in a vector then return it. I would have to check with other if statements then specifically save last element if I needed to

Comment: If you need to do something special with the last element then add `if` like `if (i == v.size() - 1)` in the `for` loop.

Comment: @noobcoder What high level problem are you really trying to solve?

Comment: I am trying to find how many growing number sequences are there in a vector then save them in a matrix one under another.  songyuanyao's answer is okay, but if I use more than 1 loop the ending result of the code will be ugly . . .

Comment: @noobcoder -- You could have used the `std::is_sorted_until` algorithm function, as [seen here](http://ideone.com/qw8N7M).  Basically, we're calling that function repeatedly, starting from the beginning of the sequence until where the sequence is out of order, and then doing something with that data (adding it to a matrix).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this section of code:

```
  for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    {
        if(v.at(i) <= v.at(i+1))
        {
            // code
        }
    }
```

`v.at(i+1)` will go past the end of the vector in the final iteration of the loop.  If you change the condition in the loop to be `i < v.size()-1` this will solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Below is how I would write this code:

```
auto prev = begin(v);
auto it = prev;
if(it == end(v))
    return;
it ++;
for(; it != end(v); it++, prev++)
{
    if(*prev <= *it)
    {
        //code
    }
}
```

There are a few benefits:

1. It will work with multiple types of containers including `list` and arrays such as `int v[] = {10,20,30,40,50};` or `array<int, 5>`
2. The iterator can be forward only and does not have to be random access.
3. If you need the index, you can still get it from `distance(begin(v), it)`

**Demo**: [link](http://ideone.com/lQ51ik)

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions.

What if your vector has only one element?

That might never happen, but I would check for it anyway.

Then I find it easier in these situations to use two index variables in case I need to manipulate the two elements later.

```
bool fun(std::vector<int> v)
{
    if (v.size() == 1)
        return true; // Perhaps you would return false?

    for(int i = 0, j = 1; i < v.size() && j < v.size() - 1; i++, j++)
    {
        if(v.at(i) <= v.at(j))
        {
            // code
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll post this as an answer, even though I placed it in the comments.

Given your description of storing growing sequences in a matrix, the following example code using [std::is_sorted_until](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_sorted_until) can be used in a simple `do-while` loop.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

bool fun(std::vector<int>& v)
{
    // our matrix
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix;

    // initially point to beginning of vector
    auto startIter = v.begin();
    auto iter = startIter;
    do 
    {
        // return first item that is out of order
        iter = std::is_sorted_until(startIter, v.end());

        // save everything as a matrix row, 
        // starting from beginning up to the item that's out of order
        matrix.push_back({ startIter, iter });

        // set new starting position to the position of the 
        // item out-of-order
        if ( iter != v.end())
            startIter = iter;
    } while (iter != v.end());  // keep going until we reach the end

    return true;
}
```

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/BixYit)

The comments in the above example should be enough to explain what is occurring.

The point being is that whenever you're writing a loop that works on a sequence of data, always think that there may be an algorithm or set of STL algorithm functions that makes the job easier.  In this case, that algorithm was `std::is_sorted_until`.

---

You can make the above more generic by using purely iterators:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

template <typename Iter>
bool fun(Iter iter1, Iter iter2)
{
    // our matrix
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix;

    // initially point to beginning of vector
    auto startIter = iter1;
    auto iter = startIter;
    do 
    {
        // return first item that is out of order
        iter = std::is_sorted_until(startIter, iter2);

        // save everything as a matrix row, 
        // starting from beginning up to the item that's out of order
        matrix.push_back({ startIter, iter });

        // set new starting position to the position of the 
        // item out-of-order
        if ( iter != iter2)
            startIter = iter;
    } while (iter != iter2);  // keep going until we reach the end

    return true;
}

int main()
{
    int arr [] = { 1,2,3,2,5,6,4,8,3 };
    fun(arr, std::end(arr));
}
```

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/gosNQ3)